# jQuery function isn't always working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that has to send data to a processing page once the button is clicked

```
<button id="whatever" onclick="sendData(); echoContent();">Send</button>
```

And here is the code itself:

```
function echoContent() {
   $('#main_content').load('parts/echo.php');
}

function clearField() {
   document.getElementById("content_input").value='';
   document.getElementById("header_input").value='';
}
function sendData() {
   var header = jQuery('#header_input').val();
   var content = jQuery('#content_input').val();

   jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'parts/addData.php',
      data: {
          header: header,
          content: content
      }
    });

    clearField();

}
```

And the  that is to be updated once the page is loaded, and, once the button is clicked:

```
<div id="main_content"><script type="text/javascript"> echoContent(); </script></div>
```

There is no problem with the `echoContent()` function once the button is clicked once, but the second time, the content doesn't refresh

Maybe there is an error in the placement of the functions?

Comment: you should use $(document).ready(function (){  //funcions   });

Comment: Is the form accidentally submitted? Do you expect `echocontent` to load the data which you just `sendData`ed? This is not ensured with *a*jax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK!,or Try this optimally code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function echoContent() {

        $.ajax({
            url: "parts/echo.php",
            type: 'GET',
            data: null,
            dataType: 'html',
            beforeSend: function () { 
                $('#main_content').html("Loading data...");
            },
            success: function (data) {
               $('#main_content').html(data);
            },
            complete: function () { 
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });

    }

    function clearField() {

        $("#content_input").val(""); 
        $("#header_input").val("");

    }

    function sendData() {

     var header = $('#header_input').val(); 
     var content = $('#content_input').val(); 

     $.ajax({
            url: "parts/addData.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                header: header,
                content: content
            }, 
            beforeSend: function () {  
            },
            success: function (data) {
               if($.trim(data)){
                    clearField();
                    echoContent();
               }
            },
            complete: function () { 
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });

    }  

$(function(){

    echoContent();

    $("#whatever").click(function(){
        sendData(); 
    });

});

</script>

<div id="main_content"></div>
<button id="whatever">Send</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is jQuery caches your `.load()` calls by default, so you need to use `.ajax()` with cache option instead, or disabling global ajax caching with following code:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({ cache: false });
```

Execute that at start of your script and your `.load()` calls will not get cached and you will see newer content everytime you call it.

Answer (score -1):

I can see several things possibly going wrong.

First of all, your sendData function is asynchronous.  The Javascript interpreter will immediately go on to call the echoData function without waiting for the $.ajax call in sendData to complete.  A better way to do this would be to call echoContent from the success handler in $.ajax like so:

Also, you may want to clear out the content of #main_content before your $.load call:

```
function echoContent() {    
    $('#main_content')
        .html('') // clear it out
        .load('parts/echo.php');
}

function sendData() {
    var header = jQuery('#header_input').val();
    var content = jQuery('#content_input').val();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'parts/addData.php',
        data: {
            header: header,
            content: content
              }
         },
        success(response) {
            // Runs when addData.php is finished
            echoContent();
        });

      clearField();

   }
```